# Curl connection refused port 80 and 443

Tags: php, curl

I have a function that I have deduced is failing specifically the curl_exec.
the error response i get from curl is

```
    Failed to connect to www.domain.co.za port 80(and same for 443): Connection refused
```

here is my function

The weird thing is this stopped working only yesterday after being stable for months

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is failing?

the url that it goes to is correct and works if entered in to the browser

```
    private function post_to_callback($url, $fields) {
        unset($fields->raw);
        //url-ify the data for the POST
        $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
        //mail('anthony@domain.co.za','debug',$fields_string);
        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        // $count = 1;
        // $url = str_replace("https://", "http://", $url, $count);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        //tried this and it didnt work
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);


    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);

        mail('anthony@domain.co.za','curl error','<pre>'. curl_error($ch) .'</pre>');
    }

    //echo $result;

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

EDIT: here is the script that it tries to curl to

```
<?php
mail('anthony@domain.co.za','debug','it got to the beginning of callback');
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'full_name');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$number = '0' . substr(str_replace('+', '', filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'phone_number')), -9);

mail('anthony@d9omain.co.za','debug','it got to the campaign');

$campaign = "Herbal Peel - Parkhurst - April 2018";
$friendly = "Herbal%20Peel%20Special";
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "Last signup " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
foreach($_POST as $k => $p) {
fwrite($myfile, "$k => $p \r\n");
}
fwrite($myfile, "$name $email $number $campaign");

// Connect to foreign MySQL database
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'db', 'db', 'db');
$query = "INSERT INTO cosmag_leads (campaign, name, number, email, date,friendly_name) VALUES ('$campaign', '$name', '$number', '$email', NOW(),'$friendly');";
mail('anthony@domain.co.za','debug',$query);
fwrite($myfile, $query);
mysqli_query($link, $query);
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Connection refused is self explanatory : your packets went out to the said address, but either they are not listening or they barred you from accessing. Time to call them i guess.

Comment: it is sent to a folder on the same server should i post the script that it is sent to? will that help

Comment: nope : solve the communications issue. Dont change your code until you have that straightened out. The code you already posted should work `if` the server is still up and listening to these ports.

Comment: I called my hosting company and they said there was nothing wrong in the logs, 10 minutes after calling them it works, perhaps they reset something, thanks for the direction anyway

Comment: there is no such thing as a coincidence :)